# Python Turtle stamp same shape/image at different positions

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to stamp the same shape (image I'm adding to turtle) in multiple positions on my canvas. But, it seems like every time I stamp the second shape, the first one disappears.

Is there a way to display multiple stamps on a canvas using the same shape/image? This doesn't seem to be a problem when using shapes already in turtle.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to stamp any number of copies of the same image without them disappearing until you request them to do so.  For a custom polygon shape:

```
from turtle import Screen, Shape, Turtle

POLYGON = (
    (10, 10),
    (0, 10),
    (-10, 0),
    (0, -10),
    (10, -10),
)

screen = Screen()

screen.register_shape('house', Shape('polygon', POLYGON))

turtle = Turtle('house')
turtle.penup()

for x in range(-200, 200, 30):
    turtle.setx(x)
    turtle.stamp()

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Or for a custom image shape:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

IMAGE = "home-5-24.gif"  # https://www.iconsdb.com/gray-icons/home-5-icon.html

screen = Screen()

screen.register_shape(IMAGE)

turtle = Turtle(IMAGE)
turtle.penup()

for x in range(-200, 200, 30):
    turtle.setx(x)
    turtle.stamp()

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]